# error: could not find implicit value for parameter d: io.circe.Decoder[List[TableInfo]]

Tags: scala, circe

I have the following code that does not compile and returns this error:

error: could not find implicit value for parameter d: io.circe.Decoder[List[TableInfo]]

```
     r <- segmements.as[List[TableInfo]]
```

[Code]

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder
import io.circe.parser

val json: String =
"""
{
    "segmements": [
        {
            "tableName": "X",
            "segmentName": "XX",
            "pocs": [
                "aa@aa.com",
                "bb@bb.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tableName": "Y",
            "segmentName": "YY",
            "pocs": [
                "aa@aa.com",
                "bb@bb.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""

final case class TableInfo(tableName: String, segmentName: String)
object TableInfo {
  implicit final val TableInfoDecoder: Decoder[TableInfo] = deriveDecoder
}

val result = for {
  data <- parser.parse(json)
  obj <- data.asObject.toRight(left = new Exception("Data was not an object"))
  segmements <- obj("segmements").toRight(left = new Exception("Json didn't had the 
segments key"))
  r <- segmements.as[List[TableInfo]]
} yield r

println(result)
```

scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/eVEvBulOQwGzg5hIJroAoQ/3

Comment: Well, as you can see in the **Scastie** the code actually compiles. So you probably modified it in some way, try to replicate your changes in the **Scastie** to replicate the error.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I copy pasted the entire code from scastie and ran it in scala repl again. It gives me an error while running it there. I read that this might be due to the sealed trait not present, could that be the case?

Comment: these were my library dependencies in the build.sbt file:  "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.13.0",
    "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.13.0",
    "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.13.0"   Can you please tell me if the version is correct for the solution you provided yesterday?

Comment: If you pasted in in the REPL and were not cautious about making sure the `TableInfo` class and object were evaluated at the same time, they probably didn't become companions and thus the implicit was not in scope. Try with a `import TableInfo._` before the `val result = for {` it should work.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much! I'll update the solution

Answer (score 1):

I added import import TableInfo._ to the code before val result as @
Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez recommended and the code worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder
import io.circe.parser
import io.circe._

val json: String =
"""
{
    "segments": [
        {
            "tableName": "X",
            "segmentName": "XX",
            "pocs": [
                "aa@aa.com",
                "bb@bb.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tableName": "Y",
            "segmentName": "YY",
            "pocs": [
                "aa@aa.com",
                "bb@bb.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""

final case class Tables(segments: List[TableInfo])
object Tables {
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Tables] = (cursor: HCursor) =>
    for {
      segments          <- cursor.downField("segments").as[List[TableInfo]]
    } yield Tables(segments)
}

final case class TableInfo(tableName: String, segmentName: String)
object TableInfo {
  implicit final val TableInfoDecoder: Decoder[TableInfo] = deriveDecoder
}

val result = io.circe.parser.decode[Tables](json)

println(result)
```

Comment: Pay attention that the key list name now is `segments`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I get this error in implicit val and impliciti final val statements: Cyclic reference involving val <import>  how do I correct this?